# What does intrinsic and extrinsic mean?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, terminology

When I read books of geometry, I sometimes find the term "intrinsic" and "extrinsic" but don't understand them precisely.

What are definitions of them? Are intrinsic properties more important than extrinsic properties?

Comment: could you give an example of these books' usage?

Comment: Can you explain what you didn't understand or found unsatisfying when you searched for the terms in the context of differential geometry? For example, I think that the beginning of [Wikipedia's page of differential geometry of surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces) has a good first explanation (at the time of this comment).

Comment: Gaussian curvature is intrinsic one.

Comment: @marimo: But for surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$, Gaussian curvature is *defined* extrinsically. So it's one of Gauss's deep results that it in fact does turn out to be intrinsic (i.e., dependent only on the metric and not on the embedding).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will try to address the question in the context of differential geometry of manifolds. A property of a manifold is termed *intrinsic* if it depends only on distances as measured within the manifold. In a more mathematical language, intrinsic properties depends on the **metric**, or the **first fundamental form**. On the other hand, a property is termed *extrinsic* if it depends on the way you embed your manifold in an higher dimensional Euclidean space. An example of extrinsic 'property' is the **second fundamental from** from which you can deduce the **shape operator**.

Another important example that may use the term intrinsic is the **curvature**. Gauss's **Theorema Egregium** asserts that the curvature is an intrinsic property of a manifold - because it can be deduced from the metric.